# How to set the position of title of button

Tags: ios, swift

Here I am writing Arabic latter on the title of button.And make the title label in centre align  But problem is that some arabic latter touches the buttom boundary of button and some top boundary of button. How i resolved it

my code is

```
 optionA.setTitle(Option[0], forState: .Normal)
 optionB.setTitle(Option[1], forState: .Normal)
 optionC.setTitle(Option[2], forState: .Normal)
 optionD.setTitle(Option[3], forState: .Normal)
```

Hare optionA,optionB,optionC,optionD are the button and the Option is the array of arabic latter

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this

```
let button = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
button.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 200, height: 72)
button.setTitle("مرحبا", for: .normal)
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0)
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

And change the `button.titleEdgeInsets` as preferred.